# Conversion of jQuery code into Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me in converting jQuery code to Vanilla javascript

```
$('.currency,.excludeCurrency').each(function () {
    new AutoNumeric(this, { 
        allowDecimalPadding: "floats", 
        modifyValueOnWheel: false 
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you try anything? SO is not get code for free site

Comment: Read this maybe:  http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.currency, .excludeCurrency');
elements.forEach((item) => {
    new AutoNumeric(item, { allowDecimalPadding: "floats", modifyValueOnWheel: false });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [much easier way](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/#initialize-multiple-autonumeric-objects-at-once) to do that than what Damian Peralta used:

```
AutoNumeric.multiple('.currency, .excludeCurrency', {
    allowDecimalPadding: 'floats',
    modifyValueOnWheel: false,
});
```